# woocommerce_api_authentication_error in POST ios

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I am using AFOAuth1Client for oauth 1.0. It works fine for GET request but for the POST everytime I get an error "oauth_consumer_key parameter is missing" in ios. Here is my code:

```
let client = AFOAuth1OneLeggedClient(baseURL: NSURL(string: Constants.kBASEPATH), key: Constants.kOAUTH_CUSTOMER_KEY, secret: Constants.kOAUTH_CUSTOMER_SERCET)
    client.parameterEncoding = AFJSONParameterEncoding
    client.oauthAccessMethod = "POST"
    client.signatureMethod = AFOAuthSignatureMethod.AFHMACSHA1SignatureMethod

    client.postPath("orders", parameters: dictParameter, success: { (operation, responseObject) -> Void in
        print("responseObject: \(responseObject)")
        }) { (operation, error) -> Void in
            print("error:\(error)")
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

What is the base URL that you're using? Is it v2 or v3? For me, it works fine on v2 but gives me a "invalid signature" error for v3

Comment: Thanks for your answer i have already solved it. I'm using v3 and We can not posted parameter for v3 we need to pass them in the url path and also for invalid signature you need to append "&" after encoding in your secret key then it will works like a charm...